# ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Display Modes with Exact View Name

Tags: mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have set up the Display Mode in Application Start event as

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert( 0, new DefaultDisplayMode( "iPhone" ){
ContextCondition = ( context => 
    context.GetOverriddenUserAgent( ).IndexOf( 
        "iPhone", 
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) >= 0 ) } );
```

Then in the controller I have return View where I specify the view name:

> return View( "~/Views/Common/User/Login.cshtml", viewModel );

And if I visit the page from the iPhone it will go directly to Login View

If I do not specify the view name:

```
return View( viewModel );
```

In this case from the iPhone I see the Login.iPhone.cshtml

**Question**: Is it possible to specify the name of the view but some how the DisplayModeProvider will select general or iPhone version of the cshtml file?

Comment: Haven't tried MVC4 yet, but have you tried not specifying the complete path of the view, but rather just the view name. `return View("Login",viewModel);`  With MVC3 and the mobile-enabled view engine, it would then pick the `Login.Mobile.cshtml` view for mobile and `Login.cshtml` view for non-mobile.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have some views in a special paths, so we need to provide the absolute path. so default viewName (based on the action) and the name of the view in shared folder is OK, but absolute path is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally like to resurrect old questions but as this one was never answered and this is one I had particular trouble finding an answer to myself, it may be worth having an answer for anyone else who comes across the same problem.

You could add your additional locations to the ViewLocationFormats and PartialViewLocationFormats collections for the ViewEngines you are using. This way you could just specify the view name as tvanfosson suggests and MVC would find the file correctly, which should allow the mobile overriding to work it's magic.

Here is some code I use to override the PartialViewLocationFormats, you could also do the same using ViewLocationFormats. This is added in global.asax as part of application_start

```
            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine
            {
                PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
                {
                    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/{1}/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/{1}/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml"
                }
            };
```

Because this method involves clearing the viewengines collection, you will need to add in all locationFormats, even the standard ones, for all the view engines you are using.